# How to pass args to an instance of sublime_plugin.WindowCommand?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I create a plug-in for sublime text 3, the designed Command Palette.sublime-commands is as follows:

```
[
{
    "caption": "Function 1", 
    "args": {parameter:"y"}, 
    "command": "generalfunc"
}, 
{
    "caption": "Function 2", 
    "args": {parameter:"n"}, 
    "command": "generalfunc"
}
]
```

actually, I want to pass the args to the sublime_plugin instance below:

```
class GeneralFuncCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def __init__(self, parameter=None):
        self.parameter = parameter
        super(GeneralFuncCommand, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        if self.parameter =='y':
            do something
        elif self.parameter =='n':
            do something else
        else:
            pass
```

What is the proper way to pass args to the GeneralFuncCommand class? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a plugin/python newb, but I put something together that works for me.

The "**args" seems to be the key in the "def" line.  Seems to be a wildcard to make all other params available via the args['myparamnamehere'] syntax.  I've seen other scripts name that param "**kwargs" so maybe you could google that for more examples (I found tons of examples, but no docs on the how's or the why's of it).  There may be a better way, but this is all I found after a couple hours of work on my own project, so I'm just sticking with it.

```
class dgReplaceLibCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, **args):
        if (args['replaceSet'] == "CFML to cfScript"):
            self.cfml_to_cfscript(edit)
```

I'm guessing your def line needs to look like this...

```
def __init__(self, **args):
```

And then you would access your param like this (again, guessing)...

```
self.parameter = args['parameter']
```

Also, you may need to put quotes around the key "parameter" in  your config. I haven't seen too many in the examples that weren't quoted.  I.e...

```
"args": {"parameter":"y"},
```

Hope this helps!